# How can I lead users to new route instead the current route in my controller ? Symfony

Tags: symfony, controller

I'd like to lead users to a new route when he has submitted the search form. The new route will be named "events". In order to get all data that I need, I let him to stay on search. At the moment, it's the only way I have found to pass the two selections the user has made from search and events saved in database.

Thank you very much for help.

I am willing to share more about my code or show to you what I've tried.

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Front;

use App\Entity\Events;
use App\Entity\BigCity;
use App\Entity\Country;
use App\Entity\Language;
use App\Form\SearchType;
use App\Repository\EventsRepository;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

class EventsController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/search', name: 'search')]
    public function search(
        Request $request, 
        SessionInterface $sessionInterface,
        EventsRepository $eventsRepository,
    ){   
        $data = $request->request->all();
        $sessionSearchFormData  = $sessionInterface->get('searchFormData');

        $form = $this->createForm(SearchType::class, ['data' => $sessionSearchFormData]);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            $data = $form->getData();
            $sessionInterface->set('searchFormData', $data);
            
            $events = $eventsRepository->findAll();
            
            return $this->render("front/events.html.twig", [
                'bigcity'=> $form->get('bigcity')->getData()->getId(), 
                'category'=> $form->get('category')->getData()->getId(), 
                'events' => $events
            ]);

        }
        return $this->renderForm('front/search.html.twig', [ 
            'form' => $form,
        ]);
    }

    #[Route('/events', name: 'events')]
    public function events(
        Request $request, 
        EventsRepository $eventsRepository, 
        CategoriesRepository $categoriesRepository, 
        BigCityRepository $bigCityRepository
    ){
        $events = $eventsRepository->findAll();

        $category = $categoriesRepository->find($request->query->get('category'));
        $bigcity = $bigCityRepository->find($request->query->get('bigCity'));

        return $this->render("front/events.html.twig", [
            'events' => $events,
            'category' => $category,
            'bigcity' => $bigcity
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use the [Redirect to Route](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#redirecting). Adding query parameters to the redirect. Pass the id's of the events object, then in your events route controller, get those events by the ids in the query string..

Comment: Thank you Bossman. I have tried your solution but it looks like I didn't understand how to pass the values in query parameters. I will answer to my question with what I have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last time we have forget getId() here

```
'category'=> $form->get('category')->getData()
'bigcity'=> $form->get('bigcity')->getData()
```

and that's why you was redirect to **localhost:8888/gozpeak/public/events?** without any parameter

Now it should be like this

```
$queryStringParameters = http_build_query([
    'category'=> $form->get('category')->getData()->getId(),
    'bigcity'=> $form->get('bigcity')->getData()->getId()
 ]);
```

So **based on your code** this should works fine , tested on local. Just copy and paste the two functions in place of others if it works, you can edit them as you like later

```
#[Route('/search', name: 'search')]
public function search(Request $request, SessionInterface $sessionInterface)
{
    $sessionSearchFormData = $sessionInterface->get('searchFormData');

    $form = $this->createForm(SearchType::class, ['data' => $sessionSearchFormData]);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        $data = $form->getData();
        $sessionInterface->set('searchFormData', $data);

        $queryStringParameters = http_build_query([
            'category'=> $form->get('category')->getData()->getId(),
            'bigcity'=> $form->get('bigcity')->getData()->getId()
        ]);

        $url = $this->generateUrl("events").'?'.$queryStringParameters;

        return $this->redirect($url);

    }
    return $this->render('front/search.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ]);
}

#[Route('/events', name: 'events')]
public function events(Request $request, EventsRepository $eventsRepository, CategoriesRepository $categoriesRepository, BigCityRepository $bigCityRepository)
{
    $events = $eventsRepository->findAll();
    $categories = $categoriesRepository->findAll();

    $category = null;
    $bigcity = null;

    if ($request->query->has('category')) {
        $categoryId = $request->query->get('category');
        $category = $categoriesRepository->find($categoryId);
    }
    if ($request->query->has('bigCity')) {
        $bigCityId = $request->query->get('bigCity');
        $bigcity = $bigCityRepository->find($bigCityId);
    }


    return $this->render("front/events.html.twig", [
        'events' => $events,
        'categories' => $categories,
        'category' => $category,
        'bigcity' => $bigcity
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you hous and welcome back ! Your solution leaded me to this error ```Impossible to access an attribute ("name") on a null variable.```

Comment: what is the url you was redirected to ?

Comment: http://localhost:8888/gozpeak/public/events?category=2&bigcity=1

Comment: This corresponds with the categories and big cities registered in the database.

Comment: very good , you are now redirect with the right parameters and right values. You have now category and bigcity in the url, nice.
Now je job is in events function. is it the same as mine or no ? if you can add the events function to the question or doing dd($category) and after thet dd($bigCity) and show the output

Comment: Ok. $category and $bigcity must not be null, so I changed a little your solution.

Comment: I just updated the description with my code.

Comment: Currently I have the error ```The identifier id is missing for a query of App\Entity\BigCity``` so now I'll try dd($category) and dd($bigcity).

Comment: Ok, I just have the id filled in. All other fields are null.

Comment: category and bigcity are query string parameters after "?" and with "&" , so you have just their ids in the url not the object.

Comment: so remove $category,    $bigcity from the parameters of events function and try to retrieve those parameters value the "ids" and select the category and the bigcity from the database using those ids

Comment: I have tried this ```$category = $categoriesRepository->findOneBy($request->query->get('category'));``` but I have this error ```Argument #1 must be of type array, string given```

Comment: when you say $bigcity = $bigCityRepository->find($bigCityId); so $bigcity will be and object , pass him in the render view and in the twig you do {{ bigcity.name_attribute }}

Comment: try findOneById

Comment: or if you want to use findOneBy, so you should pass an array
$categoriesRepository->findOneBy(['id'=> $request->query->get('category'))]);

Comment: Ok, I get it. ```findOneById``` worked very well, thank you very much hous.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution :

**EventsController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Front;

use App\Entity\Events;
use App\Entity\BigCity;
use App\Entity\Country;
use App\Entity\Language;
use App\Form\SearchType;
use App\Repository\EventsRepository;
use App\Repository\BigCityRepository;
use App\Repository\CategoriesRepository;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

class EventsController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/search', name: 'search')]
    public function search(
        Request $request, 
        SessionInterface $sessionInterface,
        EventsRepository $eventsRepository,
    ){   
        $data = $request->request->all();
        $sessionSearchFormData  = $sessionInterface->get('searchFormData');

        $form = $this->createForm(SearchType::class, ['data' => $sessionSearchFormData]);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            $data = $form->getData();
            $sessionInterface->set('searchFormData', $data);
            
            $events = $eventsRepository->findAll();
            
            return $this->redirectToRoute("events", [
                'bigcity'=> $form->get('bigcity')->getData()->getId(), 
                'category'=> $form->get('category')->getData()->getId(), 
                'events' => $events
            ]);
        }
        return $this->renderForm('front/search.html.twig', [ 
            'form' => $form,
        ]);
    }

    #[Route('/events', name: 'events')]
    public function events(
        Request $request, 
        EventsRepository $eventsRepository, 
        BigCityRepository $bigcityRepository,
        CategoriesRepository $categoriesRepository
    ){
        $events = $eventsRepository->findAll();
        $category = $categoriesRepository->findOneById($request->query->get('category'));
        $bigcity = $bigcityRepository->findOneById($request->query->get('bigcity'));
        return $this->render("front/events.html.twig", [
            'events' => $events,
            'category' => $category,
            'bigcity' => $bigcity
        ]);
    }
}
```